# Best steps to start saving money for a fresh grad in Singapore?

Tags: savings, singapore

What steps should a fresh graduate in Singapore undertake to start saving money or growing money?

Comment: Your profile says you're in Singapore.  Are you looking for advice specific to there?

Comment: If specific to Singapore,that will be more helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Singapore is one of the world's most expensive countries to live in. Step 1: leave Singapore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, make sure annual income exceeds annual expenses. The difference is what you have available for saving.

Secondly, you should have tiers of savings. From most to least liquid (and least to most rewarding):

1. (optional) **Credit cards.** Having available credit might save your bacon, and rewards cards can juice your income and savings a small bit: by (ab)using the grace period effectively, you can shift more money into less liquid accounts. But you need to pay in full monthly to make this worthwhile.
2. **Demand deposits** (aka checking) & **cash**. Make sure you have enough to cover expenses for say 30 days.
3. **Savings account**. This serves two purposes: to set aside money for lumpy expenses and for emergencies. The rule of thumb is to have 6 months worth of expenses built up. Remember that these accounts are limited in transactions per month, so if you do need to move money in or out, move enough to cover at least 15 days.
4. **Roth IRA**. I really like these things, since you can pull the dollars you put in  out without penalty. If it's been open for five years you can also pull out the earnings for a home downpayment. One sneaky benefit is that you can actually use this to retire early, as a lifetime of contributions could take a long time to draw down.
5. **Traditional IRAs, 401(k)s, and other retirement accounts**. These are long term, tax advantaged accounts you put money in that you don't touch for like 40 years. They're pretty illiquid, but sometimes you can take a loan out against them in emergencies to avoid penalties for early withdrawl. Since money here is in for a long while, you can put most of it into riskier investments like stocks and bonds.

The core of personal finance is managing the flow of money between these tiers to balance maximizing return on savings with [budget constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_constraint). For example, insurance effectively allows society to move money from savings to stocks and bonds. And a savings account lets the bank loan out a bit of your money to people buying assets like homes.

Note that the above set of accounts is just a template from which you should customize. You might want to add in an FSA or HSA, extra loan payments, or taxable brokerage accounts, depending on your cash flow, debt, and tax situation.

Comment: Tip: Check assumptions first.  Might not be a U.S. question.

Comment: True. The fundamental liquidity vs return tradeoff exists everywhere, but your options, especially tax advantaged ones may change depending jurisdiction.

Comment: Credit cards don't help you save money, they help you spend money. Dumb advice.

Comment: Credit reduces the amount of money you need to have in short term savings. If you have 50 bucks in checking, a 55 dollar bill due on Thursday and a 500 dollar paycheck on Friday, you don't have to pull out 5 dollars from savings and can in fact move an extra 50 dollars into savings.

Comment: But this is all *really* optional; these rewards checking and credit account rely on a substantial set of clueless people to subsidize people like me who fully maximize the system.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that you are now making some amount X per month which is more than the income you used to have as a student. (Otherwise, the question seems rather moot.) All figures should be net amounts (after taxes).

First, figure out what the difference in your cost of living is. That is, housing, electricity, utilities, the basics that you need to have to have a place in which to live. I'm not considering food costs here unless they were subsidized while you were studying. Basically, you want to figure out how much you now have to spend *extra* per month for basic sustenance.

Then, figure out how much more you are now making, compared to when you were a student. Subtract the sustenance extra from this to get your net pay increase.

After that is when it gets trickier. Basically, you want to set aside or invest as much of the pay increase as possible, but you probably have other expenses now that you didn't before and which you cannot really do that much about. This mights be particular types of clothes, commute fares (car keepup, gas, bus pass, ...), or something entirely different. Anyway, decide on a savings goal, as a percentage of your net pay increase compared to when you were a student. This might be 5%, 10% or (if you are really ambitious) 50% or more. Whichever number you pick, make sure it's reasonable giving your living expenses, and keep in mind that anything is better than nothing.

Find a financial institution that offers a high-interest savings account, preferably one with free withdrawals, and sign up for one. *Each and every time you get paid*, figure out how much to save based on the percentage you determined (if your regular case is that you get the same payment each time, you can simply set up an automated bank transfer), put that in the savings account and, for the moment, *forget about that money*. Try your best to live only on the remainder, but if you realize that you set aside too much, don't be afraid to tap into the savings account. Adjust your future deposits accordingly and try to find a good balance. At the end of each month, deposit whatever remains in your regular account into your savings account, and if that is a sizable amount of money, consider raising your savings goal a little. The ultimate goal should be that you don't need to tap into your savings except for truly exceptional situations, but still keep enough money outside of the savings account to cater to some of your wants.

Yes, bank interest rates these days are often pretty dismal, and you will probably be lucky to find a savings account that (especially after taxes) will even keep up with inflation. But to start with, what you should be focusing on is not to make money in terms of real value appreciation, but simply figuring out how much money you really need to sustain a working life for yourself and then walking that walk.

Eventually (this may take anywhere from a couple of months to a year or more), you should have settled pretty well on an amount that you feel comfortable with setting aside each month and just letting be. By that time, you should have a decently sized nest egg already, which will help you get over rough spots, and can start thinking about other forms of investing some of what you are setting aside.

Whenever you get a net pay raise of any kind (gross pay raise, lower taxes, bonus, whichever), increase your savings goal by a portion of that raise. Maybe give yourself 60% of the raise and bank the remaining 40%. That way, you are (hopefully!) always increasing the amount of money that you are setting aside, while also reaping some benefits right away.

One major upside of this approach is that, if you lose your job, not only will you have that nest egg, you will also be used to living on less. So you will have more money in the bank and less monthly expenses, which puts you in a significantly better position than if you had only one of those, let alone neither.

Comment: @Grace, hint: joining meta with the same account will earn you 100 rep.